# Make anything in Container not Transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/b09pbs4v/

What I'm trying to accomplish is **as the user scrolls, I would like anything in the bordered container to show be not transparent (opacity:1)**.  
It would also be awesome to also have as it goes in the box to be not transparent to have a sort of transition to opacity:1.

I don't think this is achieve in CSS, and I'm still learning jquery|javascript.
Thank you!

As a bonus question: How would this affect the website in mobile because I certainly don't want this effect on mobile.  I'd like this specifically for anything else and for mobile, just opacity:1.

```css
.box{
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  background:gray;
  font-size:20px;
  overflow:auto;
 
}
.box p{
  opacity:.5;
}
.boxtwo{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  opacity:.5;
}
.make-me-solid{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
}

body,html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <div class="make-me-solid"></div>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sodales quam quis dapibus congue. Praesent efficitur odio quis est sodales, id sagittis nisl euismod. Sed lacinia, enim vitae interdum imperdiet, quam lacus vehicula eros, eu feugiat ligula risus at justo. Morbi id varius diam. Nullam risus neque, porta eu nisl id, rhoncus malesuada justo. Sed a arcu hendrerit, fringilla nulla id, fringilla nisl. Suspendisse vehicula sollicitudin lacinia. Proin quis nibh efficitur, consectetur lectus at, eleifend purus. Nullam finibus libero eget ante venenatis finibus. Phasellus ultrices magna non maximus imperdiet. Vestibulum euismod rhoncus tortor, eu tincidunt leo placerat et. Vestibulum convallis dapibus turpis ut consequat.
  </p>
  <div class="boxtwo"></div>
    <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sodales quam quis dapibus congue. Praesent efficitur odio quis est sodales, id sagittis nisl euismod. Sed lacinia, enim vitae interdum imperdiet, quam lacus vehicula eros, eu feugiat ligula risus at justo. Morbi id varius diam. Nullam risus neque, porta eu nisl id, rhoncus malesuada justo. Sed a arcu hendrerit, fringilla nulla id, fringilla nisl. Suspendisse vehicula sollicitudin lacinia. Proin quis nibh efficitur, consectetur lectus at, eleifend purus. Nullam finibus libero eget ante venenatis finibus. Phasellus ultrices magna non maximus imperdiet. Vestibulum euismod rhoncus tortor, eu tincidunt leo placerat et. Vestibulum convallis dapibus turpis ut consequat.
  </p>
    <div class="boxtwo"></div>
    <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sodales quam quis dapibus congue. Praesent efficitur odio quis est sodales, id sagittis nisl euismod. Sed lacinia, enim vitae interdum imperdiet, quam lacus vehicula eros, eu feugiat ligula risus at justo. Morbi id varius diam. Nullam risus neque, porta eu nisl id, rhoncus malesuada justo. Sed a arcu hendrerit, fringilla nulla id, fringilla nisl. Suspendisse vehicula sollicitudin lacinia. Proin quis nibh efficitur, consectetur lectus at, eleifend purus. Nullam finibus libero eget ante venenatis finibus. Phasellus ultrices magna non maximus imperdiet. Vestibulum euismod rhoncus tortor, eu tincidunt leo placerat et. Vestibulum convallis dapibus turpis ut consequat.
  </p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Please post any javascript or jquery you have tried - even if it's not working. And, please post a specific question. Right now the "question" comes off as an attempt to solicit free labor rather than seeking help resolving a coding problem.

Comment: The question is specific enough: Make anything in container not transparent.  I've tried multiple things in javascript but as I said, I'm not good with it, if I come up with anything useful, I'll post it here but I don't see this as free labor, I'm asking for help not forcing people to help me.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service , or a tutorial service. There are lots of tutorials and plugins available regarding this topic. You need to make attempts yourself to solve problem and when you have problems with real code ask questions then

Comment: Ok, so give me a web tutorial or plugin since there's so many because I haven't been able to find any

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you tried to do something of that kind, but it should be the other way round and opacity might no be a good idea.

*You can easily disable any CSS via mediaqueries*

```css
.box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.box p {
  opacity: .5;
}
.boxtwo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: .5;
}
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html:after {
  content: '';
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 15vw;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9));
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sodales quam quis dapibus congue. Praesent efficitur odio quis est sodales, id sagittis nisl euismod. Sed lacinia, enim vitae interdum imperdiet, quam lacus vehicula eros, eu feugiat ligula
    risus at justo. Morbi id varius diam. Nullam risus neque, porta eu nisl id, rhoncus malesuada justo. Sed a arcu hendrerit, fringilla nulla id, fringilla nisl. Suspendisse vehicula sollicitudin lacinia. Proin quis nibh efficitur, consectetur lectus
    at, eleifend purus. Nullam finibus libero eget ante venenatis finibus. Phasellus ultrices magna non maximus imperdiet. Vestibulum euismod rhoncus tortor, eu tincidunt leo placerat et. Vestibulum convallis dapibus turpis ut consequat.
  </p>
  <div class="boxtwo"></div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sodales quam quis dapibus congue. Praesent efficitur odio quis est sodales, id sagittis nisl euismod. Sed lacinia, enim vitae interdum imperdiet, quam lacus vehicula eros, eu feugiat ligula
    risus at justo. Morbi id varius diam. Nullam risus neque, porta eu nisl id, rhoncus malesuada justo. Sed a arcu hendrerit, fringilla nulla id, fringilla nisl. Suspendisse vehicula sollicitudin lacinia. Proin quis nibh efficitur, consectetur lectus
    at, eleifend purus. Nullam finibus libero eget ante venenatis finibus. Phasellus ultrices magna non maximus imperdiet. Vestibulum euismod rhoncus tortor, eu tincidunt leo placerat et. Vestibulum convallis dapibus turpis ut consequat.
  </p>
  <div class="boxtwo"></div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sodales quam quis dapibus congue. Praesent efficitur odio quis est sodales, id sagittis nisl euismod. Sed lacinia, enim vitae interdum imperdiet, quam lacus vehicula eros, eu feugiat ligula
    risus at justo. Morbi id varius diam. Nullam risus neque, porta eu nisl id, rhoncus malesuada justo. Sed a arcu hendrerit, fringilla nulla id, fringilla nisl. Suspendisse vehicula sollicitudin lacinia. Proin quis nibh efficitur, consectetur lectus
    at, eleifend purus. Nullam finibus libero eget ante venenatis finibus. Phasellus ultrices magna non maximus imperdiet. Vestibulum euismod rhoncus tortor, eu tincidunt leo placerat et. Vestibulum convallis dapibus turpis ut consequat.
  </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly I suggest you the following jQuery code.

This is attached to the mouse hover, but if you need something of different let me know.

For mobile connections you may set the opacity just to 1 as a fixed value.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.boxtwo, make-me-solid').hover(
    function(e) {
      $(this).stop().animate({'opacity': 1}, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('opacity', 0.5);
      });
    },
    function(e) {
      $(this).stop().animate({'opacity': 0}, 500);
    });
});
```

```css
.box{
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  background:gray;
  font-size:20px;
  overflow:auto;

}
.box p{
  opacity:.5;
}
.boxtwo{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  opacity:.5;
}
.make-me-solid{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
}

body,html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
    <div class="make-me-solid"></div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sodales quam quis dapibus congue. Praesent efficitur odio quis est sodales, id sagittis nisl euismod. Sed lacinia, enim vitae interdum imperdiet, quam lacus vehicula eros, eu feugiat ligula risus at justo. Morbi id varius diam. Nullam risus neque, porta eu nisl id, rhoncus malesuada justo. Sed a arcu hendrerit, fringilla nulla id, fringilla nisl. Suspendisse vehicula sollicitudin lacinia. Proin quis nibh efficitur, consectetur lectus at, eleifend purus. Nullam finibus libero eget ante venenatis finibus. Phasellus ultrices magna non maximus imperdiet. Vestibulum euismod rhoncus tortor, eu tincidunt leo placerat et. Vestibulum convallis dapibus turpis ut consequat.
    </p>
    <div class="boxtwo"></div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sodales quam quis dapibus congue. Praesent efficitur odio quis est sodales, id sagittis nisl euismod. Sed lacinia, enim vitae interdum imperdiet, quam lacus vehicula eros, eu feugiat ligula risus at justo. Morbi id varius diam. Nullam risus neque, porta eu nisl id, rhoncus malesuada justo. Sed a arcu hendrerit, fringilla nulla id, fringilla nisl. Suspendisse vehicula sollicitudin lacinia. Proin quis nibh efficitur, consectetur lectus at, eleifend purus. Nullam finibus libero eget ante venenatis finibus. Phasellus ultrices magna non maximus imperdiet. Vestibulum euismod rhoncus tortor, eu tincidunt leo placerat et. Vestibulum convallis dapibus turpis ut consequat.
    </p>
    <div class="boxtwo"></div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sodales quam quis dapibus congue. Praesent efficitur odio quis est sodales, id sagittis nisl euismod. Sed lacinia, enim vitae interdum imperdiet, quam lacus vehicula eros, eu feugiat ligula risus at justo. Morbi id varius diam. Nullam risus neque, porta eu nisl id, rhoncus malesuada justo. Sed a arcu hendrerit, fringilla nulla id, fringilla nisl. Suspendisse vehicula sollicitudin lacinia. Proin quis nibh efficitur, consectetur lectus at, eleifend purus. Nullam finibus libero eget ante venenatis finibus. Phasellus ultrices magna non maximus imperdiet. Vestibulum euismod rhoncus tortor, eu tincidunt leo placerat et. Vestibulum convallis dapibus turpis ut consequat.
    </p>

</div>
```